# How to pass value to constructor this.setstate in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

Currently I want to `setState` of `userId` inside the constructor. The thing I want is to get the `firebase.auth.currentUser.uid` stored to the `userId` when Login is successful or `handleLogin` called.

I have a poor knowledge in Programming. So please ignore the other errors in the programs.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, 
          Text, 
          View, 
          TouchableOpacity,
          AsyncStorage,
        } from 'react-native';

import {RkTextInput, RkButton } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer  } from 'react-navigation';

import Profile from "../Profile/Profile";
import SignUp from '../SignUp/SignUp';


import * as firebase from 'firebase';


export default class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state=({
      email:'savadks1919@gmail.com',
      password:'123123',
      userId:'',
      errorMessage: null
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done();
  }
    _loadInitialState = async () => {
      let value= await AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.userId)
    }
    signup() {
      Actions.signup()
    }
    Home() {
      Actions.home()
    }

    handleLogin = (email, password, userId) => {

      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(

        this.setstate ({
          userId: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        }),
        alert(this.state.userId)

     ).catch(function(error) {
         var errorCode = error.code;
         var errorMessage = error.message;

         if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
             alert('Wrong password.');
         } else {
             alert(errorMessage);         
         }
         console.log(error);
     });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Taams</Text>
        <Text style={styles.edition}>Developer's Edition</Text>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Login.js</Text>
        <Text>Alpha 0.0.0.1</Text>

        {/*-----UserName Input-------*/}
        <RkTextInput 
            rkType= 'rounded' 
            labelStyle= {{color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
            placeholder='UserName'
            //--------------value Handler----------------//
            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}

            //---------------------------------//
            selectionColor="#000000"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            onSubmitEditing={() => { this.password.focusInput(); }}
            inputStyle={{
            color: 'black',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}/>


         {/*-----Password-------*/}
        <RkTextInput 
            secureTextEntry={true}
            rkType= 'rounded' 
            placeholder='Password'
            //--------------value Handler----------------//
            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}

            //---------------------------------//
            ref={(input) => { this.password = input; }}
            inputStyle={{
            color: 'black',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}/>

        <RkButton onPress = {()=>this.handleLogin(this.state.email,this.state.password)}>
          <Text style={styles.LoginButtonText}>Login</Text>
        </RkButton>

           <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
            <Text style={styles.signupText}>Don't have an account yet?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.signup}><Text style={styles.signinButton}>SignUp</Text></TouchableOpacity> 
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  signupTextCont:{
    flexGrow: 0,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'flex-end',
    marginVertical:15
},
signupText:{
    color:'rgba(64,64,64,0.6)',
    fontSize:16
},
signinButton:{
    color:'#000000',
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'500'
},
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  edition: {
    fontSize: 15,
    //fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  TextInput: {
    width: 300,
    height:50,
    borderColor: 'grey',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  LoginButtonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    //alignItems: 'center'

  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are coming from different screen with navigation on login screen then you need to pass userId in Params of react-navigation like this

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', params)`

and get these params in your constructor like this to get the userId

`this.props.navigation.getParams('params')`

if you are on the login screen and calling your auth function for authentication of user and also you need this Data in your component then you need to setState on the response of your auth function

`setState({userData: res})`

Or you can do initialisation inside constructor

`this.state={ userId: firebase.auth.currentUser.uid }`

Comment: Thanks for replay but it is little  confusing for me. all i need is to get firebase.auth().currentUser.uid vlaue inside the userId which is inside the contractor

Comment: @SvdKs then make a state in your constructor and initialise with firebase.auth().currentUser.uid like 
this.state={ userId: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid }

Comment: Answer Accepted